# fifo linux - write() function terminates the program abruptly

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, fifo

I'm implementing a pipe in C, where multiples producer programs (9 in my case) write data to one single consumer program.

The problem is that some producers (some times one or two) exit the program abruptly when calling the write() function.

The code is simple, here is the producer code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MSG_SIZE_BYTES 4

void send(unsigned int * msg){

    int fd, msg_size;
    int r;
    char buffer [5];
    char myfifo[50] = "/tmp/myfifo";

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);

    if(fd == -1){
        perror("error open SEND to fifo");
    }

    r = write(fd, msg, MSG_SIZE_BYTES);

    if(r == -1){
        perror("error writing to fifo");
     }

    close(fd);
    printf("Message send\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int cluster_id = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int msg[1];
    msg[0] = cluster_id;

    while(1){
        printf("Press a key to continue...\n");
        getchar();
        send(msg);
    }
}
```

And here is the consumer code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MSG_SIZE_BYTES 4

int receive(unsigned int * received_msg){
    int fd, msg_size;
    int ret_code;
    char buffer [5];
    char myfifo[50] = "/tmp/myfifo";

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    if(fd == -1) 
       perror("error open RECV to fifo");

    ret_code = read(fd, received_msg, MSG_SIZE_BYTES);

    close(fd);

    if (ret_code == -1){
        printf("\nERROR\n");    
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void main(){

    mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo", 0666);

    unsigned int msg[1];
    while(1){
       receive(msg);
       printf("receive msg from id %d\n", msg[0]);

    }
}
```

I'm compiling the producers and consumer with the following command: gcc -o my_progam my_program.c

To reproduce the problem, you need to open 9 terminals to run each producer and 1 terminal to run the consumer.
Execute the consumer: ./consumer

Execute the producer in all terminals simultaneously, passing to each execution an associated ID passed by command line. Ex: ./producer 0, ./producer 1.

After the producer send messages some times (10 in average), one arbitrary producer will abruptly stop its execution, showing the problem.

The following image depicts the execution:
[Terminals ready to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Fye.png)

The following image depicts the error on producer ID 3
[Error on producer 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiqKm.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What value does errno have?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By abruptly I understand that it crashes, but it's hard to tell why based on what you provided. A wild guess is that you are violating memory by reading out of `msg` buffer.

Comment: The code does not advances to the point to check the errno. Seems the something inside the write function exits the whole program.

Comment: You still continue to write/read even if  `open` is failed.

Comment: If a remove the close(fd) of both codes everything works fine, however doing this is not a the right way.

Comment: Can you get the exit status of the failed program?

Comment: No error is printed after open(), thus I assume that open is working properly before the program exit inside the write()

Comment: can you include [mcve] so that we can test ourselves?

Comment: Ok, I will try to isolate the problem in a verifiable example.

Comment: Run the producer under gdb or another debugger to debug the program.

Comment: I UPDATED the question providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Run the process under [the `strace` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and see what system calls it does make - and what signal(s) it may get, such as `SIGPIPE`.  `strace -o /path/to/strace/output/file command [args ...]`

Comment: strace returned a broken pipe: 
EPIPE (Broken pipe) --- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=14118, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
I'm looking for alternatives to handle this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the consumer program closes the reading end of the pipe after reading data:

```
fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

if(fd == -1){
     perror("error open RECV to fifo");
}
ret_code = read(fd, received_msg, MSG_SIZE_BYTES);

close(fd);
```

All other writers, which are currently trying to `write()` data (i.e. are blocked in the `write()`-syscall) now receive a `SIGPIPE`, which leads to program termination (if no other signal handling is specified).

Your consumer program may not close the filedescriptor while producers are writing. Just read the next datum without closing.

Comment: I commented the close(fd) of the consumer. It works for more time, but after consumer receive a long set of messages, it show the error: 

error open RECV to fifo: Too many open files, which makes sense, since the consumer opens the fifo at each loop. I tried to call the open() function of consumer before the while loop, but do not work since the open is needed to make the handshake between the producer and consumer at each exchanged message.

Comment: If you do not close it, you of course don't have to open it either (only the first time)

Comment: If a put the open() at the beginning (outside of the consumer loop), the consumer program stalls and never enters in the loop.

Comment: If you place the `open()` for reading from the FIFO outside the loop, the consumer will not get a return until the first producer runs its own `open()` for writing to the FIFO.  After that, the consumer will periodically get EOF when no producer has the FIFO open.  It must, at that point, reopen the FIFO for reading, which will again cause it to wait for the next producer to open the FIFO. See also [Having trouble getting a Unix FIFO to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221732/) and [Weird behaviour of FIFOs on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17776370/) amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

Problem SOLVED:

The problem is that I was opening and closing the FIFO at each message, generating a Broken pipe in some write attempts. Removing the close() and inserting the open() function for BOTH producer and consumer at the begging of the code instead inside the loop solved the problem.

Here is the code of producer with the bug fixed:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MSG_SIZE_BYTES 4

int my_fd;

void send(unsigned int * msg){

    int fd, msg_size;
    int r;
    char buffer [5];
    char myfifo[50] = "/tmp/myfifo"

    if(fd == -1){
        perror("error open SEND to fifo");
    }

    r = write(my_fd, msg, MSG_SIZE_BYTES);

    if(r == -1){
        perror("error writing to fifo");
     }

    //close(fd);
    printf("Message send\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int cluster_id = atoi(argv[1]);
    unsigned int msg[1];
    msg[0] = cluster_id;

    my_fd = open("/tmp/myfifo", O_WRONLY);

    while(1){
        printf("Press a key to continue...\n");
        getchar();
        send(msg);
    }
}
```

And here is the consumer code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MSG_SIZE_BYTES 4

int my_fd;

int receive(unsigned int * received_msg){
    int fd, msg_size;
    int ret_code;
    char buffer [5];
    char myfifo[50] = "/tmp/myfifo";

    if(fd == -1) 
       perror("error open RECV to fifo");

    ret_code = read(my_fd, received_msg, MSG_SIZE_BYTES);

    //close(fd);

    if (ret_code == -1){
        printf("\nERROR\n");    
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void main(){

    mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo", 0666);
    my_fd = open("/tmp/myfifo", O_RDONLY);

    unsigned int msg[1];

    while(1){
       receive(msg);
       printf("receive msg from id %d\n", msg[0]);

    }
}
```

Thank you all!!